# Malformed url exception linux local file system

Tags: linux, selenium, malformedurlexception

I have been trying to execute a selenium.attachFile command to upload a file-

sel.attachFile(dom_locator,"/home/xyz/Desktop/tstfl.txt");

but getting a Malformed URL Exception for the file path specified. The file is present in the linux local file system. Please help me with the proper format of the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely what you need is

```
sel.attachFile(dom_locator,"file:///home/xyz/Desktop/tstfl.txt");
```

For an explanation of file uris, see [File URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) in wikipedia.